# How to add a value to an associative array that was pulled from a database?

Tags: php, arrays

So imagine an array being like so.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [value_1] => 10
            [value_2] => 15
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [value_1] => 10
            [value_2] => 15
        )

    [value_3] => 20
)
```

How would you get [value_3] to go in both rows without it being in the database like so?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [value_1] => 10
            [value_2] => 15
            [value_3] => 20
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [value_1] => 10
            [value_2] => 15
            [value_3] => 20
        )
)
```

I don't really understand how to do this, and I've tried many ways. So I'm either making a mistake with the foreach loop itself or I'm bad at for loops.

Comment: loop through your array and do something like `$my_array[$i]['value_3'] = $my_array['value_3'];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop the array and add the new key to each of them, using `&` in order to get the reference, otherwise the change won't take effect on the original array:

```
$dbArr = array(array('value_1' => 10, 'value_2' => 15), array('value_1' => 10, 'value_2' => 15));

foreach ($dbArr as &$arr) {
    $arr['value_3'] = 20;
}
```

Remember to use `&$arr` so that you get the reference of the given sub-array, and be able to modify it.

Comment: Wow, I actually never knew about the `&` part in the array. Thanks for telling me what ti does and explaining it. The code now works correctly as it should :)

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to loop through the database result, which I call `$yourArrays` in the following example.

```
foreach ($yourArrays as &$anArray){
    $anArray['value_3'] = 20; 
}
```

Comment: That's what I have, but the ['value_3'] still remains at the bottom of the array instead of in [0] and [1].

Comment: Try adding the `&` so the value is passed by reference

Answer (score 1):

Possible method:

```
$YourArray[0]['value_3'] = 20;
$YourArray[1]['value_3'] = 20;
```

Edit:

```
foreach($YourArray as $Key) {
    $YourArray[$Key]['value_3'] = 20;
}
```

Comment: How would I get each row? with a for loop?

Answer (score 1):

Don't miss the `&` when you loop with the foreach.

```
$array = [
    [ 'value_1' => 10, 'value_2' => 15 ],
    [ 'value_1' => 10, 'value_2' => 15 ]
];

foreach ($array as &$value){
    $value['value_3'] = 20; 
}

var_dump($array);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = array(
    array(
        'value_1' => 10,
        'value_2' => 15,
    ),
    array(
        'value_1' => 10,
        'value_2' => 15,
    )
);

$value_3 = 20;

foreach($array as $key => $row) {
    $array[$key]['value_3'] = $value_3;
}

var_dump($array);
```